# pass variable to php modal

Tags: php, css

I am having this trouble whereby I want to delete items based on their ids. However, in modal, it doesn't get the specific id for me to delete. Instead, it gets the the ids which are the lowest first. For example, if I delete a product with an id of 88, it will deletes the id before it first such as number before 88. How can I delete specifically items with the right id?

```html
<?php
ob_flush();
session_start();
include('includes/header.php'); 
include('includes/navbar.php'); 
if($_SESSION['admin_name']){
    //do nothing
}
else{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.top.location='http://localhost/CarRentalv3/admin/adminlogin.php';</script>"; exit;
}
$admin_name = $_SESSION['admin_name'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href=" http://localhost/CarRentalv3/img/CarRent.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css">
    <title>Admin Panel | Admin List</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="modal fade" id="addadminprofile" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Admin Data</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action="process.php" method="POST">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Admin Name </label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Position</label>
                <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Position">
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" name="register_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<!-- DataTales Example -->
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
  <div class="card-header py-3">
    <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">Admin Profile 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addadminprofile">
              Add Admin Profile 
            </button>
    </h6>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['success'])&& $_SESSION['success']!=''){
    echo '<h2 class="bg-primary text-white">'.$_SESSION['success'].'</h2>';
    unset ($_SESSION['success']);
}
if(isset($_SESSION['status'])&& $_SESSION['status']!=''){
    echo '<strong>'.'<h2 class="bg-danger text-white">'.$_SESSION['status'].'</strong>'.'</h2>';
    unset ($_SESSION['status']);
}
?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <?php
    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","admindb");
    $query = "select * from admin";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);



    ?>
      <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th> ID </th>
            <th> ADMIN NAME </th>
            <th>EMAIL </th>
            <th>POSITION</th>
            <th>EDIT </th>
            <th>DELETE </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
     <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run)>0){
         while($rows= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
                        ?>
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo $rows['id'];?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['admin_name'];?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['admin_email'];?></td>
             <td><?php echo $rows['admin_position'];?></td>

            <td>
                <form action="register_edit.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="edit_id" value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>">
                    <button  type="submit" name="edit_btn" class="btn btn-success"> EDIT</button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                             <form action="process.php" method="POST">
                             <input type="text" id="id"  readonly value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?> ">
                <button type="button" name="delete" onclick="myFunction();"id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>  



            </td>
          </tr>

                    <?php
         }
     }
     else{
         echo "no record found!";
     }
        ?>
         <div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
   <!-- Modal content-->  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                        <br>
                     <h5 class="modal-title">PIN Required</h5>  
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button> 
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body"> 

                     <label>PIN</label>  
                    <input type="text" id="print" readonly  >
                     <input type="password" name="pin" id="password" class="form-control" />  
                     <br />  
                     <button type="submit" name="delete_btn" id="pin_button" class="btn btn-warning">Confirm</button>  

                 <div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  

 </div>
 </form>

        </tbody>
      </table>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("print").value = document.getElementById("id").value;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php
ob_end_flush();
include('includes/script.php');
include('includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("print").value = document.getElementById("id").value;` You are creating buttons with `id=delete` inside your while loop. So you end up with a lot of buttons with the same id which is both invalid html and creates your problem here.

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou so what is the proper solutions that i should use to get the correct result?

Comment: Reading more of your code I see more problems. You also open your `<form>` tag inside your while loop and you close it in your modal. That will also create invalid html since you'll be opening a lot of form tags and only closing one of them. You should either move your whole form inside the modal or outside of it. You can pass the id in your function eg `onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $rows['id'];?>');"`

Comment: @DimitrisFilippou can you show me how to correct my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating buttons with `id="delete"` inside your while loop. So you end up with a lot of buttons with the same id which is both invalid html and creates your problem here.

You also open your  tag inside your while loop and you close it in your modal. That will also create invalid html since you'll be opening a lot of form tags and only closing one of them.

Without having seen the code on your `process.php` file it is not 100% that the fixes here will solve your issue so bear that in mind.

First of all change

```
<td>
    <form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="id"  readonly value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?> ">
    <button type="button" name="delete" onclick="myFunction();" id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>  
</td>
```

to

```
<td>
    <button type="button" name="delete" onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $rows['id'];?>');" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal">Delete</button>  
</td>
```

Then change your function

```
function myFunction(print_value) {
  document.getElementById("print").value = print_value;
}
```

Lastly change your modal body

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
    <label>PIN</label>  
    <input type="text" id="print" readonly  >
    <input type="password" name="pin" id="password" class="form-control" />  
    <br />  
    <button type="submit" name="delete_btn" id="pin_button" class="btn btn-warning">Confirm</button>  
</form>
```

and remove the other closing form tag `</form>` you have before `</tbody>`